# Create a dict without if

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function to generate dictionary but without if.
Example:

```py
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
```

But sometimes year is not available for some models and instead of using if, want to create a function with parameters: brand, model, year. Once year is None or any other attributes is None, then avoid it.

Like:

Year is None

```py
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang"
}
```

What do you think, is that possible to create without if?

Comment: Why not use an if statement?

Comment: What exactly do you mean not using ```if```?  Please include your actual code.

Comment: What horrible things have `if` done to you, making you not want to use it? Please share your code `if` you want help. :)

Comment: how do you pass the data in the first place? Why not pass it as a dictionary from the start?

Comment: share the code so may be we can help us

Comment: If you really dont want to use If then use numpy.where or match case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are talking about this. you can use `kwargs`.

```
def generate_dict(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

generated_dict = generate_dict(name='John', age=30)
# {'name': 'John', 'age': 30}
```

Comment: You could call the `dict` directly like this: `dict(name='John', age=30)`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the dictionary keys and remove the keys with value `None`:

```
def create_dictionary(brand, model, year = None):
    res =  {
        "brand": brand,
        "model": model,
        "year": year
    }

    res = { k:v for k,v in res.items() if v is not None}
    return res 
    
print(create_dictionary("Ford", "Mustang"))
```

Output:

```
{'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang'}
```

Comment: In addition to being far more complicated than it needs to be, that still uses an `if`.